# How can i copy selected text file using command "FOR" in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, copy

Hello guys as you read in topic how can i make a selected file to copy to another location.
Im using my own Lithuanian language in this, if some one find it hard to understand tell me ill translate it. Right now it only creates new file when i start " name.bat test.txt" its not full code since there is lots of copy paste of same thing any ideas since im realy bad at .bat files.
And i need to use command "FOR"

```
:DEKUPAZAS
echo Pasirinkote Dekupazo kursus
echo Bendrine informacija apie si bureli
echo.
type dekupazas.txt
echo.
set U=dekupazas.txt
echo Ar norite:
echo 1) Irasyti sia informacija i naujai sukurta faila?
echo 2) Grizti kitu bureliu pasirinkimu?
echo 3) Grizti prie srities pasirinkimo?
choice /C 123 /N /M "Iveskite savo pasirinkima(1,2 arba 3): "
if errorlevel 255 goto KLAIDA
if errorlevel 3 goto SRITIS
if errorlevel 2 goto KT
if errorlevel 1 goto IRASYMAS
goto PRADZIA

:IRASYMAS
echo Pasirinkote irasyti sia informacija i jusu sukurto pavadinimo faila
echo Failas bus perkeltas i aplanka Pasirinkimas
if exist Pasirinkimas rd /S /Q Pasirinkimas
md Pasirinkimas
for %%U in (U) do dir %%U >>%1
move %1 Pasirinkimas >nul
goto PAB
```

Comment: try with `for %%U in (%U%) do dir %%U >>%1`

Comment: If you are trying to parse the contents of the file dekupazas.txt, then you need to use a **FOR /F** command.

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR /F` statement reads each line of the file then does a directory listing of it captured to the first parameter to the .bat script.

I also took the liberty of creating a variable for the new directory name so that it does not need to be hardcoded so many times.  "Hardcode" is two, four-letter words.

```
echo Pasirinkote irasyti sia informacija i jusu sukurto pavadinimo faila
echo Failas bus perkeltas i aplanka Pasirinkimas
SET NEW_DIR=Pasirinkimas

if exist "%NEW_DIR%" (RMDIR /S /Q "%NEW_DIR%")
MKDIR "%NEW_DIR%"

for /F %%a in (%U%) DO (DIR "%%~a" >>"%~1")
move "%~1" "%NEW_DIR%" >nul
goto PAB
```

Comment: Well new i guess i have a diffrent problem as you can see i declare U as name.txt but at the start i have to run like name.bat choice.txt and in that choice there should be a copy of selected name.txt i hope you understand what i say since now all i get is "file not found"

Comment: The variable U is set by `set U=dekupazas.txt`. The %1 variable would be the command line parameter from `name.bat test.txt`. The %1 variable would be `test.txt`. Please help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: This is a full code http://pastebin.com/8im46pJc the error im now I get is that "file not found"

Comment: Which file was not found? Do you have `@ECHO OFF` somewhere that is preventing you from seeing the problem?